# Excel freeze after ListBox_DblClick if the mouse cursor is moved outside the Listbox during the event

Tags: excel, vba, window, userform

### Context

I'm using the `Listbox_DblClick` event of on an Excel Userform (within a .xlam AddIn) to do a bunch of thing (which mainly update the Userform, but alost does some external logging...). Those actions can take up to a few seconds.

### Problem

Excel winbdows are let almost frozen if the user move the mouse cursor outside the Listbox during the ListBox_DblClick event.

### Consequences

I cannot click anywhere on the UserForm or ActiveSheet or the VBA window. Even the close button of Excel is unresponding. But nothing seems to be running (the last line of the event has already ran, nothing visible on the CPU...)

To be able to interact with Excel again, I need to either :

- move temporarly the mouse cursor back over the ListBox
- or change temporarly the current Windows application (like by doing Alt+Tab twice).

Excel is then globally fine. There isn't any other consequence and everything runs OK after this freeze.

### What I already checked

- It's not related to an **`EnableEvents`** or **`ScreenUpdating`** issue. Those are correctly managed by the macro. Even adding two lines to set them to True at the end of the event don't resolve the issue.
- It's not that the **macro is still running**. Adding `Debug.Print "Finished"` at the end of the event show that "Finished" prints normally, while Excel is kept frozen.
- Since I don't want the user to launch a new event while the current event is still running, I prevent that by locking/delocking the many ListBox (including the one realted to the event) using **`ListBox.Locked`** at the beginning/end of the event. But commenting these lines doesn't resolve the issue.

### Minimal Reproductible Exampe

- Add an Array on a UserForm
- Add the following code

```
    Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
        For n = 1 To 3000
            Me.Caption = n
        Next n
        Me.ListBox1.List = Array("Apple")
    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Me.ListBox1.List = Array("Apple", "Banana")
    End Sub
```

- Double click on "Banana" and moove the mouse cursor

### Note

In [this post form 2012](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/903278-editing-listbox-items-in-dblclick-event-freezes-excel-unless-mouse-moves-over-listbox.html) (*Editing listbox items in Dblclick event freezes Excel unless mouse moves over listbox*), the user seems to encounter a similar issue.